# Download Ubuntu Live CD for a low RAM PC

Tags: live-cd

For pxe boot I need iso Ubuntu. The problem is when Clients requests iso from the Server and  iso is Standard Desktop Image (around 1.5 GB), Clients just do not have enough RAM...  So I need just Live CD with no option 'Install Ubuntu'.

Is it possible to download only Live CD Image and if it is please share the link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a [minimal iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), but all "Standard Desktop Images" have been well over 700MB for some years now.

Comment: mini.iso just has Ubuntu Live CD or it is package for online installation as I understand from description...? Second option is useless for my case...

Comment: You haven’t specified what you need to do in the booted Ubuntu on the clients, e.g. do whether you need GUI at all. The question is therefore too broad and opinion-based. Please [edit] your question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no officially released live image small as CD size back few years from now.

You could choose to go with other derivatives of Ubuntu or Debian, or even Debian itself.

Few options:

- Ubuntu Mini Remix <300MB
- List of Linux/BSD live images with estimated size to help choose from

  [livecdlist.com/media/cd/](http://livecdlist.com/media/cd/)
- [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/search.php#advanced) advanced search

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Minimal ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) With [Xfce Desktop Environment](https://www.xfce.org/)

Comment: I do not need installation! 
I need only one option 'Live CD' (Try Ubuntu) with no installation!

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to your question is already in a comment, there are several "minimal iso's" out there that you can grab that only the essential for installing something like Ubuntu 14.04 to something much older like 10.04 or 09.04 if necessary.

But I'll try to give you a different perspective that you already have, if your problem is RAM consumption and not processing power (f.e. a pentium 4 it's a good CPU even this days) I **strongly recommend that you go something designed to be lightweight**.

I personally choose Arch Linux because I'm kind of a geek (or wannabe) and Arch just give a blank piece of paper and says "write me".

Other distributions like Manjaro (recommended) or Antergos don't do this and give a full Arch experience besides all the handling of actually installing the system up (which is the hardest part), if you want a stable bullet-proof system of course (not that Arch can't be stable for it's own...).

If you don't want that approach you can always go with what you know and choose Xubuntu but because it's *based* on Ubuntu it does NOT mean it's Ubuntu (same case applies with Arch-based distributions).

**TL;DR if you wan't a *lightweight system* in Ubuntu go with Xubuntu, otherwise you can explore different options outside of the Debian/Ubuntu world.**

Comment: I XUbuntu found here http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/ and it is 1.21 GB, not so much easier